# How to merge two files in the same row?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, join

I have two files.

file1:

```
Dave 734.838.9800  
Bob 313.123.4567  
Carol 248.344.5576  
Mary 313.449.1390  
Ted 248.496.2204  
Alice 616.556.4458
```

file2:

```
Bob Tuesday  
Carol Monday  
Ted Sunday   
Alice Wednesday  
Dave Thursday    
Mary Saturday
```

I want to merge these two into file3.

file3 should look like:

```
Name      On-Call     Phone  
Carol     MONDAY      248.344.5576  
Bob       TUESDAY     313.123.4567  
Alice     WEDNESDAY   616.556.4458  
Dave      THURSDAY    734.838.9800  
Nobody    FRIDAY      634.296.3356  
Mary      SATURDAY    313.449.1390  
Ted       SUNDAY      248.496.2204
```

So how can i do this in a shell script?

Comment: I have a one-liner which does not include the sort - `awk 'BEGIN {printf("%s %10s %10s \n" ,"Name", "On-Call", "Phone")} FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2 FS $3;next}{ print $0, a[$1]}' file1.txt file2.txt | column -t`

Comment: You could also look into this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23124511/shell-script-that-will-combine-two-files-into-another-file. I believe it's the same ask.

Answer (score 3):

The `join` utility is intended for exactly this kind of problem: it joins two files based on one of their fields, by default the first one. The files should be sorted first; so

```
join <(sort file2) <(sort file1) | column -t
```

produces

```
Alice  Wednesday  616.556.4458
Bob    Tuesday    313.123.4567
Carol  Monday     248.344.5576
Dave   Thursday   734.838.9800
Mary   Saturday   313.449.1390
Ted    Sunday     248.496.2204
```

This is sorted by name rather than by weekday; you'd need some post-processing to sort by weekday if necessary...